# How to estimate branded organic traffic?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

I was wondering the best way to estimate the average number of visits my site gets each month from people who searched for my company name.

I was thinking of getting the total clicks in Google Search Console for terms that include the brand name, and then estimating how many to add in base on the % not provided. Of course GSC would only give me the traffic from Google, so I might just estimate for all other search engines based on the estimate from Google.

Would that be the best way to estimate? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Why are you considering "% not provided" for data from Google Search Console?  Search console doesn't use "not provided" as far as I know.  "Not provided" is from Google Analytics parsing the referrer strings from search engines.